# sql query combine two queries into one with empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql table structure:

Table1: details

```
    |--id--|--id_user--|--price--|
    |  1   |    1      |   10    |
    |  2   |    2      |   15    |
    |  3   |    1      |   25    |
    |  4   |    3      |   30    |
    |  5   |    3      |   7     |
    ------------------------------
```

Table2: users

```
    |--id--|--id_country--|
    |  1   |       1      |
    |  2   |       2      |
    |  3   |       0      |
    -----------------------
```

Table3: country

```
    |--id--|--country--|
    |  1   |  France   |
    |  2   |  Italy    |
    --------------------
```

What I need is to get the SUM of price by country:

```
SELECT c.country, SUM(d.price) AS price
    FROM details d
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id_user
        INNER JOIN country c ON  c.id = u.id_country
    GROUP BY c.country
    ORDER BY c.country
```

I get this:

```
|--country--|--price--|
|  France   |   35    |
|  Italy    |   15    |
-----------------------
```

**BUT I'd need to get this:**

```
|--country--|--price--|
|  France   |   35    |
|  Italy    |   15    |
| Undefined |   37    |
-----------------------
```

where `undefined` would be if `id_country=0`. (I can't add to country table the `id=0 or id=undefined`, it will messed up other things). Right now I'm achieving this by two separate queries, the second one is:

```
SELECT SUM(d.price) as price
    FROM details d 
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id_user AND u.id_country=0
    GROUP BY u.id_country
```

I'm thinking if... **is it possible to do this in one query?**

Comment: Switch to LEFT JOIN Country.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN `INNER JOIN country c`

Comment: It is strange to see that you can use an id_country in your users table that doesn't exist. That shows that you don't use your database properly. You should have a foreign key constraint and make the column nullable if you want to allow for "undefined country".

Comment: @Thorsten-Kettner can you write referring to the above example how should I construct this properly?

Comment: You'd usually create the tables with foreign keys. So you create table `Country` first with `id` being the primary key, and then you create table `users` with `users.id_country` being a foreign key to `country.id`. But you can also add this later with `alter table`. Read here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

Comment: Thank you @Thorsten-Kettner, I'd like to improve my knowledge in this matter and I'll read this tutorial. So, hopefully I'll be able to create properly those tables.

Comment: @Thorsten-Kettner, I've read the tutorial and now the foreign keys are more clear now. I'll have to redefine my tables to use FK. As you noticed I have this situation that the country can be undefined, so if I understand correctly the users table should have the id_country column set the default value for null, not to 0 as it is now? How does the query behave if it sees null? It omits this record, so it doesn't look in country table for null value?

Comment: Yes, when a value is unknown you use NULL, not 0 or -1 or 'xxx'. The queries shown so far will get the same results. So no difference here (except that the queries may become faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use left join in this case:

```
SELECT c.country, SUM(d.price) AS price
    FROM details d
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id_user
        LEFT JOIN country c ON  c.id = u.id_country
    GROUP BY c.country
    ORDER BY c.country
```

If you use INNER JOIN, you will only get results that exists in both tables.

To replace NULL with Undefined use:

```
SELECT IFNULL(c.country,'Undefined') AS Country, SUM(d.price) AS price
    FROM details d
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id_user
        LEFT JOIN country c ON  c.id = u.id_country
    GROUP BY c.country
    ORDER BY c.country
```

One way to sort to get Undefined last is to add a Sortfield

```
SELECT A.Country,A.Price FROM (
    SELECT IFNULL(c.country,'Undefined') AS Country, SUM(d.price) AS price, IFNULL(c.Country,'ZZZZZZZZ') AS Sort
        FROM details d
            LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id_user
            LEFT JOIN country c ON  c.id = u.id_country
        GROUP BY c.country
) A
ORDER BY A.Sort
```

Edit: ORDER BY suggested in comments

```
SELECT IFNULL(c.country,'Undefined') AS Country, SUM(d.price) AS price
    FROM details d
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = d.id_user
        LEFT JOIN country c ON  c.id = u.id_country
    GROUP BY c.country
    ORDER BY c.country IS NULL, c.country
```

Comment: your right, is it possible to change the "null" to "undefined" or other word and to insert at the beginning or end of the result table?

Comment: To get nulls at the end use: `ORDER BY c.country IS NULL, c.country`.

Comment: I like this middle answer starting with `SELECT IFNULL` but at the end use suggestion from @Thorsten-Kettner `ORDER BY c.country IS NULL, c.country` and works great! Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
        SELECT  
        CASE  
        WHEN c.country is NULL THEN 'Undefined'
        ELSE c.country
        END as country
        , SUM(d.price) AS price
        FROM  users u 
        left JOIN details d ON u.id = d.id_user
        left JOIN country c ON  c.id = u.id_country
        GROUP BY c.country
        ORDER BY c.country
```

For Demo :

[SqlfiddlE  Demo :](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59e829/4)

Please let us know if you have any que.